# Memory keep increasing even though I set it to nil (screenshot enclosed)

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, viewwillappear

In my ParentViewController I type this:

```
- (void)updateView:(NSInteger)_index article:(AObject *)aObject {

    UIView *aUIView = [someUIViews objectAtIndex:_index];

    // clear view
    for (UIView *view in aUIView.subviews) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }

    // create view
    ChildViewController *cvc = [[ChildViewController alloc] init:aObject context:managedObjectContext];
    cvc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [self addChildViewController:cvc];
    [aUIView addSubview:cvc.view];
    cvc = nil;
}
```

In ChildViewController I type this:

.h file

```
@interface ChildViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate> {
    AObject *aObject;
    UIWebView *webView;
}
```

.m file

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated];
    webView.delegate = nil;
    webView = nil;
    aObject = nil;
}
```

**Remark:**

- I have to use *addChildViewController* because I use *UIWebViewDelegate* in *ChildViewController*. If I do not use *addChildViewController*, I cannot retain the ViewController and functions of *UIWebViewDelegate* cannot be called.
- I use ARC

**Program Objective:**

- There is a scrolling view implementing by UIScrollView and everytime I scroll the screen to another page, function *updateView* will be called.
- After I scroll to another page, the previous page will be disappeared so *viewWillDisappear* in *ChildViewController* will be called.

**Screenshot:**

http://postimage.org/image/mzmksm9d5/

*I cannot post image directly because of low reputation here.*

Based on the figure, *ParentViewController* is called at about the 4th second. Then the memory keep increasing rapidly without objects released. At about the 30th second, *ParentViewController* is gone away by clicking the back button on the navigation bar. Memory is dropped a bit but still somethings are remaining.

**Goal:**

What I wish to do is that the object of *ChildViewController* can be destroyed when *viewWillDisappear* is called and it is no longer used. So I expect the memory would always drop after it increased a bit. Otherwise, the memory will increase proportional to scrolling times and crash until memory is fully used.

Thanks in advance for any help you are able to provide.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will solve the problem, but try removing cvc.view explicitly from parent view.

Also, you are creating ChildViewController, but you are not releasing it. By calling init you increased its retain count, but you are not decreasing it anywhere. Like this (if you do not have some more code), your ChildViewController will not be released since retain count will never be 0 again.

```
ChildViewController *cvc = [[ChildViewController alloc] init:aObject context:managedObjectContext];
cvc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
[self addChildViewController:cvc];
[aUIView addSubview:cvc.view];
cvc = nil;
```

Comment: do you mean removing [aUIView addSubview:cvc.view];? but if i do this, no view will appear. and since i am using arc, the way i can release is just set to nil. anyway, thank you for your reply.